# Error in tag separated by `|` using Regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I want to add `|` before every tag.
Please check the below code that I have used.

```
tags = ['XYZ', 'CREF', 'BREF', 'RREF', 'REF']

string_data = 'XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY'

for each_tag in tags:
    result = string_data.replace(each_tag, "|" + each_tag)
    print(result)
```

How can I do it using the Regex?

Input String:

**`XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY`**

Actual result (wrong):

**`XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYC|REF:PUNE UNIVERSITYB|REF:DADAR UNIVERSITYR|REF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLC|REF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY`**

Expected result:

**`|XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITY|CREF:PUNE UNIVERSITY|BREF:DADAR UNIVERSITY|RREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLC|REF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY`**

Is there any way to do it using regex?

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to know whether "LLCREF:" should be "LLC/REF:" or "LL/CREF:".

Comment: No needs regex. Use somenthing like this: `"|" + "|".join(['XYZ', 'CREF', 'BREF', 'RREF']) `

Comment: Your error result and expected output looks same, right?

Comment: @GaganTK No, Please check the above error result and Expected Result.

Comment: @AkshayGodase OK, got it. Can you please add your code that you tried into the question?

Comment: @GaganTK I have Update code and Actual Result (Wrong).  Please verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match an optional `B` or `R` or  match a `C` when not preceded with an `L` using a negative lookbehind.

```
(?:[BR]?|(?<!L)C)REF|^(?!\|)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[BR]?` Match an optional `B` or `R`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!L)C` Match a `C` and assert what is directly to the left is not `L`
- `)` Close group
- `REF` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `^(?!\|)` Assert the start of the string when not directly followed by a `|` to prevent starting with a double `||` if there already is one present

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrxESz/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Mt8oaX)

In the replacement use the match prepended with a pipe

```
|\g<0>
```

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?:[BR]?|(?<!L)C)REF|^(?!\|)"
test_str = "XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY"
subst = "|\\g<0>"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

print (result)
```

Output

```
|XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITY|CREF:PUNE UNIVERSITY|BREF:DADAR UNIVERSITY|RREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLC|REF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY
```

Comment: @The_fourth_bird It works successfully.  If I have tested it on another string like
`"XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLBREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY"`
Then it is not working.  This will work on any case means if before `REF` if I got any latter within A-Z` then I will work.

Comment: @The_fourth_bird  Please check the above comment highlighted string.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You could use the character class A-Z in the lookbehind. https://regex101.com/r/KtfLAR/1 But it will not match for `LLLREF` then. What is the expected in that case? Can you update the regex101 link with what should and what should not be matched?

Answer (score 2):

Since your most important problem is to split the string correctly, I have tried to address only that. You can append and prepend the `|` afterwards.

This pattern seems to be working:

```
(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF):[a-zA-Z\\s]+?(LLC)?(?=(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF)|$)
```

### Explanation:

1. `(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF):` **:** This is obvious. You are looking for the start of the tag. The order is important. That is, keep the shortest substring `REF` at the end.
2. `[a-zA-Z\\s]+?` **:** Match any character and space that occur after the tag, **reluctantly**. Reluctant, because if the engine reaches the start of `CREF`, we want it to stop there and NOT to take more characters "greedily". Because of using "reluctance", the order of tags in point (4) matters.
3. `(LLC)?` **:** This is a kind of an exception list of all known words that end with character sequences that the tags may start with. (For this, I could not think of any other way.) *The exception list must be known* and could be separately configured and appended to the pattern runtime. If the input data structure is known beforehand and such exceptions are limited and known, this is not a bottleneck. Otherwise, yes.
4. `(?=(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF)|$)` **:** A lookahead to ensure that the engine stops when it finds one of the tags coming up. `$` allows to stop at the end of the input, if there is no more tag.

This gives the following output for the input string you have provided:

```
XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITY
CREF:PUNE UNIVERSITY
BREF:DADAR UNIVERSITY
RREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLC
REF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY
```

### Edit

Adding the Python 3.8.1 code that I tested:

```
import re

s = "XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY"

p = "(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF):[a-zA-Z\\s]+?(LLC)?(?=(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF)|$)"

matches = re.finditer( p,s )

tag_list = [ m.group() for m in matches ]
s2 = "|" + "|".join( tag_list )
print( s2 )
```

Comment: @Sree_Kumar  tried the above code but not getting the result.

Comment: @AkshayGodase I have posted the code I used to test. Can you please check?

Comment: @Sreee_Kumar I have tested your code it works properly.  But I am expecting the Expected Result.  Please check the below
`|XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITY|CREF:PUNE UNIVERSITY|BREF:DADAR UNIVERSITY|RREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLC|REF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY`

Comment: I didn't want to separate all group I need above result

Comment: OK. Isn't simply joining the parts enough after this? Or do you want a solution with a regex level replacement?

Comment: Edited now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the duplication between `'CREF'`, `'BREF'`, `'RREF'` and `'REF'` - since `'REF'` is in all the other three, you will end up with duplicate replacements if you fix your code to this:

```
tags = ['XYZ', 'CREF', 'BREF', 'RREF', 'REF']

string_data = 'XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY'

for each_tag in tags:
    string_data= string_data.replace(each_tag, "|" + each_tag)
    print(string_data)
```

You need to make sure you only replace `'REF'` if it's not preceeded by a `'C'`, `'B'` or `'R'`.

Note that this would still cause issues for some cases like `XYZ:CARE BEARREF`. I.e. you might expect `|XYZ:CARE BEAR|REF`, but you'll get `|XYZ:CARE BEA|RREF`. If you want to avoid that, you need to be more precise about the actual rules.

This works, if you know this type of problem won't occur:

```
import re

string_data = 'XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY'

result = re.sub("(XYZ|CREF|BREF|RREF|REF)", r"|\1", string_data )
print(result)
```

This avoids specific checks, since regex takes into account the ordering and won't match REF after the text has already been matched as part of the previous values.

Comment: I tried your code but my expected result did not match with your result.

Answer (score 0):

import re

string = "XYZ:MUMBAI UNIVERSITYCREF:PUNE UNIVERSITYBREF:DADAR UNIVERSITYRREF:KOLHAPUR UNIVERCITY LLCREF:SOLAPUR UNIVERSITY"

regx = "(XYZ|[C|B|R]REF|REF):[a-zA-Z\s]+?(LLC)?(?=(XYZ|[C|B|R]REF)|REF|$)"

matches = re.finditer(regx, string)

tag = []

for match in matches:
    tag.append(match.group())

result= "|" + "|".join(tag)
print(result)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and congrats on your first post. You'll get a more positive response (i.e. upvotes and increased reputation) if you format your code as code, and add some text to describe why/how your answer works.